# Is it allowed to create a bot for a specific game on play store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to create a bot (auto tapper) for a specific game in google play store, I already create the code and It's work, my answer is can I publish this apps on play store, I see this rule in google policy : 
Here are some examples of common violations:
Game cheating apps that affect the gameplay of other apps.
https://play.google.com/intl/en_ALL/about/privacy-security-deception/device-network-abuse/

But I see lot of apps autotapper on the playstore, so Can I create a autotapper who already works for specific game or it's forbidden by this rule ?
Somebody have any experience with this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app store policies are off-topic  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

This would almost certainly be against the terms of the Play store for the reason given in the link in your question.

But FYI, questions about policies on app stores are [off topic for stack overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).